# ParseTwitterUtils: No login dialog appearing

Tags: android, parse-platform

I used the following in a straight copy paste from the [Parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#twitterusers):

```
ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(view.getContext(), new LogInCallback() {
@Override
public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
  if (user == null) {
      Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
  } else if (user.isNew()) {
      Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Twitter!");
  } else {
      Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!");
  }
 }
});
```

with the exception of the context I'm passing to it. Because I'm inside a button click event which is in a fragment, I pass as context: **view.getContext()**

I have also called: `ParseTwitterUtils.initialize("YOUR CONSUMER KEY", "YOUR CONSUMER SECRET");`

before everything with my API Key and API Secret. However, there is no Twitter login dialog appearing. What appears is a small rectangle with text saying: "loading..." and a moving circle, but it closes without opening any authentication dialog. Because of that the **done()** method part is never being called.

I realize that in order to use the **ParseFacebookUtils** one needs the Facebook SDK for android and that such SDK is the one that contains the Login Screen. In fact, when I use ParseFacebookUtils, it works perfectly. But there is no SDK with login screen for Twitter in Android. Plus the Parse documentation clearly states that a Twitter Login Dialog is supposed to appear when the code above is executed. No further action needed according to it.

What am I missing here. How do I make the Twitter login dialog appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have entered your consumer key, and consumer secret correctly. Next please make sure you follow item 3 in the [Parse.Com Android developer guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#twitterusers-setup) under setup.

That is, 
*3. When asked to specify a "Callback URL" for your Twitter app, please insert a valid URL. This value will not be used by your iOS or Android application, but is necessary in order to enable authentication through Twitter.*

You must specify a callback URL (a valid URL) although it won't be used. That means, use a made up URL or use something like http://myCompanyWebsite.com/callbackurl. This can be set under the "Settings" tab in your twitter developer console.

I don't use Twitter in my Parse applications, but I was able to duplicate the problem by also missing step 3 and then subsequently fix it.

If you are still having trouble please post your logcat of when you press the click button.

Comment: Thank you very much. This made it work. I had set the callback URL previously when creating the app in twitter dashboard, but it appears it never got saved. I went back after reading this and it effectively was blank. Thanks again.